# this.redirect and Router.go both error with 'has no method'

Tags: redirect, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm using Meteor version 0.8.3, iron-router version 0.8.2, and I can't get any method of redirecting to work.  I've tried both `Router.go` and `this.redirect('somepath')` and both end up with the error `Object [object Object] has no method` followed by either redirect or go.  No idea what's going on here, relevant code below:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('about2', {
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            this.redirect('about');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iron Router is mostly a client-side routing package at the moment so there's no such thing as server-side redirects, the redirect method is a client only utility which works by altering `window.location`.

Remove `where:"server"` from your route and it should work as expected.

Comment: How could one accomplish a server-side only redirect, then?

Comment: Just like you'd do in PHP : declare a server side route and return an empty response just having a `Location` header ?